# CakePHP 3 Pagination

Tags: cakephp, pagination

I am trying to make a pagination for my threads.

The code works, but I want to limit the posts per page.

How can I achieve this?
And how to draw the pagination to my threads view?

My code:

```
$this->paginate = [
         'contain' => 'posts'

        ];

     $query = $this->Threads->find('all')->where(['id' => $id]);
     $this->set('test', $this->paginate($query));
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried passing a limit option to `$this->paginate`?

```
$this->paginate = [
    'contain' => ['Posts'],
    'limit' => 10 // limits the rows per page
];
```

https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/components/pagination.html